# Getting modified keycode(char) when pressing modifier keys

Tags: c, windows, input

I'm trying to implement keyboard input in C and I don't understand how to capture modified keycodes and get a character from it. Sure, I can create a huge switch statement like this:

```c
// if (shift is pressed) {
switch (vkCode)
{
    case 0x30:
        log(")");
        break;
    case 0x31:
        log("!");
        break;
     case 0x32:
     //...
```

This would be ok for one language, but implementing this for different keyboard layouts would be a nightmare.

I found a simple way to convert a virtual key to a character that corresponds to the active keyboard layout:

```c
HKL lang = GetLang();
UINT ck = MapVirtualKeyEx(vKey, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR, lang);
printf("%c", ck);
```

Is there a way to get the modified char in a similar way?
Or how would one go about this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `"modified keycode"` and `"modified char"`? Do you want to map certain virtual keycodes to certain characters? What is wrong with your solution of using `MapVirtualKeyEx`? Does it not do exactly what you want?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Basically MapVirtualKeyEx takes a virtual key and returns a char depending on what keyboard layout you have. But it can not take into account if you are holding a modifier key down like the alt key to produce let's say a " * ".

Comment: You say you need to press the `"alt key"` to produce `*`? Do you mean the `SHIFT` key?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Yes sorry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to some pointers from Andreas Wenzel in the comments I figured out how to achieve what I wanted. Basically, we want to use `ToUnicodeEx`. It has some caveats and I would recommend reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicodeex).

To identify the language `ToUnicodeEx` takes an input locale identifier(HKL) which can be retrieved with [GetKeyboardLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayout) function.

In case someone wants to do something similar I will leave an example.

```c
if(GetRawInputData((HRAWINPUT)lParam, RID_INPUT, buffer, &dwSize, sizeof(RAWINPUTHEADER)) == dwSize)
{
    RAWINPUT* raw = (RAWINPUT*)buffer;
    if (raw->header.dwType == RIM_TYPEKEYBOARD)
    {
        const RAWKEYBOARD rk = raw->data.keyboard;
        USHORT MakeCode = rk.Message; // scanCode
        USHORT Flags    = rk.Flags;
        USHORT VKey     = rk.VKey;    // virtual Key
        UINT   Message  = rk.Message;
        ULONG  ExtraInf = rk.ExtraInformation;

        if ((Flags & RI_KEY_BREAK) != 0)
            break;

        HKL lang = GetLang();

        CHAR c[H_KEY_SIZE];
        ZeroMemory(c, H_KEY_SIZE);
        
        BYTE lpKeyState[256];
        GetKeyboardState(lpKeyState);
    
        WCHAR pwszBuff[12];
        int res = ToUnicodeEx(VKey, MakeCode, lpKeyState, pwszBuff, 12, 0, lang);
        if (res == 0)
        {
            // The specified virtual key has no translation for the current state of the keyboard.
            // Nothing was written to the buffer specified by pwszBuff.
            // Handle this if you want
        }
    
        strcat_s(c, H_KEY_SIZE, (CONST PCHAR)pwszBuff);
        printf("output: %s ", c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call [`TranslateMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-translatemessage) in your [message loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues#creating-a-message-loop), this function will cause an additional [`WM_CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-char) message to be created when a [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) message is received. This `WM_CHAR` message will contain the typed character, taking into account whether the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key is pressed. For example, if the user types a `b` will holding the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key, then the `WM_CHAR` message will contain the character code for a `B`.

As stated above, `TranslateMessage` will do all the work for you. If, for some reason, you do not want to use this function, you could try using the functions [`ToAscii`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-toascii) or [`ToUnicode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicode) instead. But, as stated in the documentation, these functions have the disadvantage that they are unable to handle [dead keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#dead-character-messages) properly. Therefore, I recommend using `TranslateMessage`.

Comment: Okay, right now I'm using WndProc and WM_INPUT to get raw keyboard input because I'm using the key inputs for a simple game as well. Is there a way to instead of listening for a WM_CHAR to directly ask for a WM_CHAR when I receive a WM_INPUT message?

Comment: I think you pointed me in the right direction. I'll look into the '''ToUnicode''' function.

Comment: @objectnabb: For a simple game, I believe it is not necessary to use raw keyboard input. It should be easier to use `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP`, although you might also need to handle `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` and `WM_SYSKEYUP`. The function `TranslateMessage` will create an additional `WM_CHAR` message. If you really need raw keyboard input, I believe it should be possible to handle `WM_INPUT` in addition to all of the other mentioned messages, but this could get messy and I doubt that this would be the best solution.